# Can I do this kind of join operation with pure SQL?

Tags: sql, join

there are some data like this:

```
name                            number

12_PAGE19901_CHN.DISPLAY_NT     n.115
12_PAGE19901_CHN.DISPLAY_NT     n.114
KAITEST123.DISPLAY_NT           n.110
KAITEST123.DISPLAY_NT           n.109
KAITEST123.DISPLAY_NT           n.108
KAITEST123.DISPLAY_NT           n.107
KAITEST33333.DISPLAY_NT         n.105
```

I want retrieve some data like this:

```
 name                            number

12_PAGE19901_CHN.DISPLAY_NT     n.115
KAITEST123.DISPLAY_NT           n.110
KAITEST33333.DISPLAY_NT         n.105
```

I need the `first` value of number for each particular name, is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you just need the max value of `number` for each particular `name`.

```
SELECT
  name,
  MAX(number) AS number
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  name
```

Be aware that as `number` is an alpha-numeric field; `n.09` is 'higher' than `n.011`.  To make this more *numerically consistent*, you would need `n.009` instead of `n.09`.

*(As I don't know the behaviour of your number field, this is just a general note, not about your example data.)*

Answer (score 1):

If you want the max for `number` and group by `name`, try this.

```
select name, max(number) as number 
from TABLE
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, 
       'n.' + Cast(Max(Cast(Substring([number], 3, Len([number]) - 2) AS INT)) 
                   AS 
                   VARCHAR(10)) 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY name
```

Comment: Good answer provided *several* assumptions about the behaviour of the `number` column.  Without a complete and categorical description from the OP as to what values are and are not possible in this field, this type of manipulation can easily fail given 'unexpected' values.